# Start/stop Windows services from Linux

Tags: windows, linux, web-services

I need to start/stop services of a Windows Server from a Linux machine.

Is there any lightweight service that gives my an interface for that or do I need to built that?

It should be an interface with an API or another sort of "machine-interface".

Can we a service on Windows that exports a protocol or
a suite that comes with serverside and clientside tool as long clientside is for linux.

Should be opensource or at least free.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Isn't something like SSH enough? Or do you want some GUI as you tagged as web service?